# ionic 4 can't use "ionic package build ios development"

Tags: angular, git, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I try to read but i can't understand the docs about ionic 4,
Can we build **ios app** with **windows** using '**ionic package build ios**'?

I try to build **ios app** with **ionic 4** using '**ionic package build ios**'

```
ionic package build ios
Build type: development

[WARN] A security profile is mandatory to build an iOS package
Security Profile Name: project_1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running git.exe rev-parse HEAD (exit code 128)
```

I try to install Git using **Git-2.25.1-64-bit.exe**
and the problem still exist..

I don't know where to post my problem, maybe somebody can help my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry but you can't build ionic (ios) apps with windows.
Ios apps require the complete ionic app to be compiled in Xcode. So you need a system running mac OS to build ios apps.

PS. For using Xcode you may require an apple id too.